# Prove that $ \lim_{t\to +\infty} ||u^\prime(t)|| = 0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I'm really confused how can we conclude $\displaystyle \lim_{t\to +\infty} ||u^\prime(t)|| = 0$ in the following paragraph:

[image]

I tried to prove when $N = 1$, but things are also difficult to handle. The author also wrote in his article that in case $N=1$, all solutions of equation $(1.1)$ are monotonic, but I do not know how to prove it either.

Comment: May be this could be wrong, but isn't there already an inequality which says that the first derivative is a non-positive function, except for the case when $u=0$ (Lsalle's invariance) which by chain of implications boils down to the author's claim $\forall N$. It is also possible to define a the $\nabla F(u)$ as a mapping function, defined by author and take the basic first derivative in terms of limit and you will get your solution.

Comment: For further understanding you can refer to this:  "Jacob, Birgit, and Hans Zwart. Linear port-Hamiltonian systems on infinite-dimensional spaces. Vol. 223. Springer Science & Business Media, 2012".

Comment: This is LaSalle's invariance principle. It is stated and proved  in J.P. LaSalle, "Some Extensions of Liapunov’s Second Method", IRE Trans. Circuit Theory, 1960 http://www.math.psu.edu/treluga/511/LaSalle1960.pdf   (Theorem 1)